# Exclude folders from Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Usually in a normal IDEA project I can hide the ".idea" folder from the project tree view by excluding it in the project structure settings. How can I achieve the same in a Gradle project? There I can still exclude that folder manually as mentioned, but then it re-appears in the project tree view after I restart IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think You can obtain solve this issue using gradle configuration.

But there are some possible solution that you can try. Try using plugin idea. Just put:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

With this plugin you can use **cleanIdea**  task to clean all .idea and .iml files.
With this plugin you can also configure how exactly idea should interpret your folder structure.

There is also simple way to hide this files once and for all. Just go to :

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types -> Ignore Files And folders
```

and there append for example something like this:

```
.idea;.gradle;build;
```

with this you would not have any problem with unnecessary files in your project structure.

Comment: That is great, thank you. Is there an online reference for all options in the "idea" plugin?

Comment: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html and google my friend :)